# Почему контекстное меню на странице меняется, если есть элемент налезающий на него?

Tags: javascript, html, webbrowser

Из-за чего браузеры, меняют контекстное меню, если какой то элемент с абсолютным позиционированием, налезает на него?

Например выделив текст и нажав правую кнопку мыши, появляется меню где присутствует кнопка копировать. (**На изображении 1**)
А если какой то элемент налазит на это меню, то оно превращается в другое? Как будто текст не был выделен. (**На изображении 2**)

***Изображение 1.*** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Изображение 2***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что это логично

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev браво))) А по теме, контекстное окно выдается с той логикой, где был (в контексте чего) клик. Скорее всего вы в последний момент кликаете именно в ваше кастомное окно, т.е. оно появляется раньше и фиксируется клик якобы не по тексту, а по псевдоокошку без текста.

Comment: Ну допустим я ткнул где-то на странице, выделив слово. И вижу картику, хочу ее сохранить, а мне предлагает скопировать слово? Контекст выделения у вас пропадает тк вы нажимаете на другой элемент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что у вас просто клик получается не по выделенному тексту, а по тому элементу, который на него "налазит".

Comment: Спасибо. Это именно из-за этого.